# Print out jQuery object as HTML

Tags: jquery

Is there a good way of printing out a jQuery object as pure HTML?

ex:

```
<img src="example.jpg">

<script>
var img = $('img').eq(0);
console.log(img.toString());
</script>
```

`toString()` doesn't work this way. I need the HTML equivalent string , i.e:

`<img src="example.jpg">`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to print the object in HTML format, use this extension [outerHTML](http://www.darlesson.com/jquery/outerhtml/) or this [outerHTML](https://gist.github.com/jboesch/889005).

**Update**

Update the link and include the code for second link:

```
$.fn.outerHTML = function(){

    // IE, Chrome & Safari will comply with the non-standard outerHTML, all others (FF) will have a fall-back for cloning
    return (!this.length) ? this : (this[0].outerHTML || (
      function(el){
          var div = document.createElement('div');
          div.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));
          var contents = div.innerHTML;
          div = null;
          return contents;
    })(this[0]));

}
```

Comment: so, I really need an extension for this? it does the same as Magnar's example, except cloning before parsing.

Comment: if the same thing, but you need to clone him to keep moving the elements in the DOM, and them remove this.

Answer (score 27):

> `$('img')[0].outerHTML`

will give you the HTML of the first img on the page. You will then need to use a for loop to get the HTML of all the images, or put an ID on the image and specify it only in the jQuery selector.

Comment: or, if you knew the specific element in the DOM that you wanted the HTML for... $('#some .selector')[0].outerHTML

Just make sure to wrap it in an if ($('#some .selector').length)

Answer (score 16):

You could wrap it and then use html:

```
var img = $('img').eq(0);
console.log(img.wrap("<span></span>").parent().html());
```

Comment: Won't it modify the DOM? Should we clone `img` first?