# How to use the jQuery constructor with more than one type of html value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jQuery constructor method to create some content and insert it throughout the DOM. Each time it's invoked, I want to create a parent div with `class="artistContactsContainer"`, a child anchor tag with `class="contactSwitch"` and a child div (`contents`) that will differ on every iteration of the `each()` loop.

```
var artists = {

        formatContacts : function() {

            var contactsContainer = function (contents) {
                // Constructor
                return $('<div/>', {
                    'class' : 'artistContactsContainer',
                    'html' : '<a href="#" class="contactSwitch"></a>' + contents
                });
            };

            $('.event-content-list').find('li').each(function(){
                var $this = $(this),
                    contacts = $this.find('.artistContacts');
                $this.find('.artistName').after( contactsContainer(contacts) );
            });
        }

};
```

The problem is that I can't seem to have two different types as values of the 'html' property. The above outputs the anchor tag followed by "[object Object]"; whereas if I remove the anchor string, the `contents` variable is output correctly.

How can I combine the two properly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print out jQuery object as HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859385/print-out-jquery-object-as-html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using the `append` function?

```
return $('<div/>', {
    'class' : 'artistContactsContainer',
    'html' : '<a href="#" class="contactSwitch"></a>'
}).append(contents);
```

---

Note that if you append a JQuery object (as above) then you will actually move the element. If you want to append a copy, then you can use `clone` like this:

```
return $('<div/>', {
    'class' : 'artistContactsContainer',
    'html' : '<a href="#" class="contactSwitch"></a>'
}).append(contents.clone());
```

Comment: This will actually **move**, not copy whatever is matched by `contacts` in OP's example. Better add `.clone` if you like appending.

Comment: fwiw: In my case moving was the desired behaviour.