# jQuery wrap() only works on the DOM, not on jQuery object?

Tags: jquery

Given the following code in javascript with jQuery:

```
var inner = $('<p></p>')
var outer = inner.wrap('<div></div>')

console.log(inner.outerHTML())       // <p></p>
console.log(outer.outerHTML())       // <p></p>
```

I understand the first output. `.wrap()` is returning the original object, for chaining purposes.

For the second output, I would expect `<div><p></p></div>` since the `.wrap()` function should modify/extend the `inner` variable.

Does the `.wrap()` only works on DOM elements? Not on a newly created jQuery object?

*Using Chorme with jQuery 2.1.1*

Comment: For starters, `.wrap()` does not take two arguments. http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: Try `$('<p></p>').wrap('<div/>').parent().outerHTML()`.

Comment: What code are you using for the `outerHTML()` method?  That doesn't appear to be standard jQuery.

Comment: you must have misunderstood it... `returning the original object`... meaning it's still the original object... so `inner.wrap('<div>')` is still inner object... and not the `div`.. cause the `div` is it's parent...

Comment: #jfriend00 just realising using outerHTML from http://stackoverflow.com/a/1859428/343475
(tought it was a core javascript function)

Comment: I thought when you use `$('selector')` it works on the DOM, but if you would do `$('<tag></tag>')` you would create a new sort of DOM where you would work on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.wrap()` works also on jQuery objects that do not reference anything in the DOM, like `$('<p></p>')`.

But you have to properly ask the result. Due to chaining, you only get the original jQuery object, but you have to ask for the newly created elements around it with `.parents()` to get your expected result.

`$('<p></p>').wrap('<div></div>').parents()`

will give: `<div><p></p></div>`

---

*notes from the OP*

It's was obvious I was not getting it before, but due to the answer and comments from @jfriend00 I became to grasp it. Also I was in doubt if a jQuery object is only a reference to something in the DOM or could be something entirly new.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. The solution is to use `parents()`.

Answer (score 2):

`.wrap()` returns the same jQuery object that you originally called it on.  The DOM has been modified, but the jQuery object has not been modified.  And, since you used `.wrap()` the element itself and it's children which is what `.outerHTML()` returns was not changed either.  Only the object's parent node was changed which is not part of `.outerHTML()` so thus you see no change.

Quoted from the [jQuery doc for `.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

> This method returns the original set
>   of elements for chaining purposes.

Thus, when you do this:

```
var outer = inner.wrap('<div>','</div>');
```

`outer` will be the same jQuery object as `inner` so, of course, they will show the same `.outerHTML()`.

A jQuery object is just a static list of DOM elements.  Internally, it just contains an array of DOM elements.  Modifying the structure around those DOM elements does not change the jQuery object in any way.  It still contains those same DOM objects.

---

So, given the above, requesting the outerHTML of a static set of DOM elements will return the exact same result whether you've wrapped it in some other element or not.  You're looking at the element itself and it's children with outerHtML.  That didn't change at all with `.wrap()`.

Comment: the OP already mentioned, "I understand the first output. .wrap() is returning the original object, for chaining purposes."

Comment: @Reigel no, I don't think the OP fully understands the implications.

Comment: @Reigel - I've added a little more explanation.

Comment: yes... that makes it more understandable... you might also want to summarize it as that `outer = inner.wrap('<div>')` is just the same as `outer = inner;`

Comment: @Reigel - added some more explanation along those lines.

Comment: So how to tell in jQuery that the string `<p></P>` is the DOM i want to work on? Maybe jQuery is a bit overkill for such string manulpulation, but I like to know.

Comment: @Rempargo - I don't understand this comment or what you're tying to do.  I think I've answered and explained the question you originally asked.  If you want the parent, you can use `.parent()` to get the parent DOM element.  Also, DOM elements are objects.  They aren't a string.